# Is setState() ignored by try & catch?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I use Firebase Auth to allow users to sign up.
If the user registers the correct email address and a sufficiently secure password, they will be registered with Firebase Auth.

I can register, but when I fail to sign up, I don't get an error.

```
String _state = ""; //global

Future signUp(String email, String password) async {
 try {
   UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
       .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
 } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
   if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
     setState(() {
       _state = ('The password provided is too weak.');
     });
   } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
     setState(() {
       _state = ('The account already exists for that email.');
     });
   }
 } catch (e) {
   setState(() {
     _state = e.toString();
   });
 }
}
```

Referred [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/).
This code executes `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` by passing the email address and password as arguments.
I'm trying to display on the screen the cause of a sign-in failure with try & catch statement.

But for some reason `setState()` doesn't change the `Text()` that has global `_state`.

```
    @immutable
class signUp extends StatefulWidget {
  static String route = '/signup';
  const  signUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _signUp createState() => _signUp();
}

class _signUp extends State<signUp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: myAppBar(context), //custom appBar. ignore this.
        body: const Center(
          child: Text( 
             _state
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I declared `Text()` in `StatefulWidget` so that it can be updated with `setState()`.

But for some reason `setState()` is ignored and `Text(_state)` is not executed.
I feel that the cause of this problem is in the try & catch statement, but I don't know what to do.

What should I do to display the sign-up results as text?

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to remove the `const` keyword before your `Center` widget. `const` makes the variable constant from compile-time.

Comment: How can you use the`setState` outside the `build` method? The `setState` only works inside its current state (inside class `_signUp` in your case).

Comment: Hi, I edited code like below, still not appears.
 - Removed const keyword before Center.
 - Move signUp() method into _signUp class.

It's awaiting in try & catch, so setState () isn't really ignored, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code like this; this solved my issue.

```
String stateCode = "";
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        stateCode = ('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        stateCode = ('The account already exists for that email.');
      } else {
        stateCode = "error: " + e.code;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      stateCode = "error: " + e.toString();
    }

    setState(() {
      _state = (stateCode);
    });
```

All I had to do was display the e.code when an exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

> I can register, but when I fail to sign up, I don't get an error.

Could you check if your sign-in really fails? Checking your code, `signUp` is a `Future<void>`. How are you handling the UserCredential being returned by `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`?

This block catches an Exception, not a successful login.

```dart
catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    _state = "Succeeded!";
  });
}
```

You can also check for UserCredential after the login request to debug.

```dart
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
       .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
debugPrint(uid: ${userCredential?.user?.uid}
```

Comment: Thank you. To recognize that creating account succeeded, I just checked list of account with firebase console of this project, and I found  accounts which I created in app. 

Also I checked with `debugPrint(userCredential.user?.uid);`, this shows uid correctly.
The problem is that the error statement when it fails cannot be displayed on the screen.

Comment: > This block catches an Exception, not a successful login.   Oh thank you. I changed code like this,        
catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    _state = e.ToString();
  });
}